# Which one is better way to detect selected value? PHP vs. jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

I'm developing my own CMS. When I load an item, I have a field for the item type which is a `<select>` and I want to change this field to the option I retrieved from DB. So I think I have two ways of doing this.

First one, in PHP, iterating over each type, I can compare the current type with the item type and if true, append `selected="selected"` to the HTML.

```
echo '<select id="itemtype">';
foreach($types as $type) {
    echo '<option value="<?=$type->id?>" <?=$type->id == $item->typeid ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>><?=$type->name?></option>';
}
echo '</select'>;
```

The other one, in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#itemtype').val('<?=$item->typeid?>');
});
```

Which one do you think is better and why?

Thanks!

Comment: My thought is PHP is better than jquery.

Comment: Do it in pure PHP. Your first suggestion. Afterall you can turn off javascript

Comment: You can measure both times and get your answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This should probably be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RiggsFolly, comparative reviews on Code Review don't often last very long. Especially seeing as the Author is asking for an explanation on which is better, not how they can improve their existing code.

Comment: @Quill regardless, it is not on topic for this site.

Comment: Maybe programmers.se?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain to me which off-topic flag this meets, or why this doesn't meet the on-topic flag of `a specific programming problem`

Comment: @Zak no, not programmers.se.  This would get closed very quickly there.

Comment: @AlbertoFernández, not everything is about performance :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways are ok, but the best choice can be done based on the following concerns:-

- If you have few types (to loop on) ... using PHP in this case will be OK
- If you have a lot of types (in the loop you will validate every type - this is cost time/execution time however you only need one type to be "selected") ... using JQuery in this case will be much better.
- Also if you are going to use Jquery ... you have to make sure that "$item->typeid" has value every time.. means if can't be NULL

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP, that way you are not mixing different languages. The least maintainable code that I always have to deal with is when there is some PHP that's echoing out a lot in HTML & JavaScript. Better to avoid such cases. As far as performance I think that there is not much of a difference to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is better to do it with PHP, because it is faster than do it with jQuery. With PHP it is also more reliable.